# Text overlay when video is recording using Directshow and C#

Tags: c#, text, overlay, directshow, directshow.net

By using DirectShowLib i can able to record the video by using ASF writter here is the code to start recording

```
 try
        {
            IBaseFilter capFilter = null;
            IBaseFilter asfWriter = null;
            IFileSinkFilter pTmpSink = null;
            ICaptureGraphBuilder2 captureGraph = null;               
            GetVideoDevice();
            if (availableVideoInputDevices.Count > 0)
            {
                //
                //init capture graph
                //
                graphBuilder = (IFilterGraph2)new FilterGraph();
                captureGraph = (ICaptureGraphBuilder2)new CaptureGraphBuilder2();
                //
                //sets filter object from graph
                //
                captureGraph.SetFiltergraph(graphBuilder);
                //
                //which device will use graph setting
                //
                graphBuilder.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Mon, null, AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name, out capFilter);
                captureDeviceName = AvailableVideoInputDevices.First().Name;                    
                //
                //check saving path is exsist or not;if not then create
                //
                if (!Directory.Exists(ConstantHelper.RootDirectoryName + "\\Assets\\Video\\"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ConstantHelper.RootDirectoryName + "\\Assets\\Video\\");
                }
                #region WMV                   
                //
                //sets output file name,and file type
                //
                captureGraph.SetOutputFileName(MediaSubType.Asf, ConstantHelper.RootDirectoryName + "\\Assets\\Video\\" + videoFilename + ".wmv", out asfWriter, out pTmpSink);                    
                //
                //configure which video setting is used by graph
                //                
                IConfigAsfWriter lConfig = asfWriter as IConfigAsfWriter;
                Guid asfFilter = new Guid("8C45B4C7-4AEB-4f78-A5EC-88420B9DADEF");
                lConfig.ConfigureFilterUsingProfileGuid(asfFilter);
                #endregion
                //
                //render the stram to output file using graph setting
                //
                captureGraph.RenderStream(null, null, capFilter, null, asfWriter);
                m_mediaCtrl = graphBuilder as IMediaControl;
                m_mediaCtrl.Run();
                isVideoRecordingStarted = true;
                VideoStarted(m_mediaCtrl, null);
```

Now i want to add an text overlay on the video when video is recoding and by using DirectshowLib is this posible?

For example when video recording get start video should get recorded with an text overlay.

Comment: You need to modify streamed data to add an overlay. Typically you use a specific and dedicated filter for this. There is no stock filter, so it is either third party or custom developed.

Comment: You typically use an extra filter in the pipeline, which modified image before int reaches encoder. Most likely, you need a third party filter for this, since writing filters in C# is somewhat complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in my software in a way that `SampleGrabber` filter is inserted into a graph, and upon arrival of a picture, I convert it to `Bitmap` object, then draw on it with `Graphics`.

Comment: Thanks Buddy for your valuable reply.but sir i m new in DirectShowLib.can u give me sample code.and is it possible to use two filter at a time.means i m already using ASF filter to record the video.and i read your answer on my second post also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860659/adding-an-image-at-the-start-of-video-file-c-sharp-and-directshow)

Comment: thanks @Daniel Mošmondor after so many long time and so much effort i can able to put an text overlay on recording video.but problem in overlay is it is not visible in some frames.why this problem occurs what i m doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Look at the DMO and DxLogo examples in the DirectShow.Net samples to do what your looking for. what Daniel Mošmondor is explaining you can find in the DxSnap example...

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/