# Adding an image at the start of Video file C# and DirectShow?

Tags: c#, video, directshow

i have code which record an video from webcam and store in "filename.wmv" format.
now i want to add an image at the start of video

How can i do this by using DirectshowLib or any other lib?
Is it possible by using DirectShow?

For my Video Recoding code go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847477/text-overlay-when-video-is-recording-using-directshow-and-c-sharp)

Comment: If you are saving to ASF and you really want to add the picture to video file already on disk,  I'll expand the answer for you...

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to add image to the start of already saved video.  If you are able to do it at the time of recording, you can use same technique I proposed in an answer to the link you provided, just don't draw overlay, but replace the whole frame with your image.

For those who won't click on the link, here's the text:

> I'm doing it in my software in a way that `SampleGrabber` filter is inserted into a graph, and upon arrival of a picture, I convert it to `Bitmap` object, then draw on it with `Graphics`.